# Bash built-in "history" can be executed, but is not in $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, sys

I know shell builtins are loaded into memory and thought I could find all builtins in /usr/bin or somewhere in `echo $PATH`. I was trying to find out how the history command works. My assumption was that it is reading from ~/bash_history. So I tried `objdump -S $(which history)`

```
which history
echo $?
```

> 1

This did not return the path of the command which makes me where the binary for history is located.

```
type -t which
builtin
```

I assume this means that it is loaded onto memory. So does a shell process load builtins that are stored outside of `echo $PATH`

Comment: If `which` is a builtin, your shell is not bash. Are you actually running zsh?

Comment: If you know about `type` already, why not run `type history`? :)

Comment: ...but, yeah, `history` *has* to be a builtin -- how could it support features like flushing the shell's in-memory history to disk without being *part of the shell's process*, and thus having access to that history?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was using bash at the time. Copied the wrong command here. Though I switched shells a few times. Just wondering, is the shell log file stored in the home directory?

Comment: If you mean the history file, there's a `HISTFILE` variable that controls where it's stored (in bash); default is `~/.bash_history`. There's no global/universal standard as to the file's location and format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell builtin is literally built into the shell executable itself. It is invoked by the shell not as a separate process, but simply as a regular function call within the shell process. So if you want to find its source code, you need to look in the [source code of `bash`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/history.def).

For many builtins, such as `cd`, the main reason for it being a builtin is that it modifies the state of the shell itself. It would be pointless to have `cd` be a separate process, as that process would only change its own current directory, not that of the shell process. In the case of `history`, the reason is presumably that `~/.bash_history` is only written when the shell exits, so the command also needs access to the in-memory history of the current session, which is contained within the running `bash` process. For other builtins, such as `echo`, the reason is performance: the command is assumed to be so frequently used that we want to avoid spawning a new process every time it is invoked (but if you really do want a process, there is also `/bin/echo`, which may behave differently).